# salesforce-ux/design-system lib is not displaying slds icons in lwc oss

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, lwc-oss, node-salesforce, lwc-dev-server

I am using LWC oss framework to play with lightning-base-components npm package. I have used 'salesforce-ux/design-system' to use SLDS.I could use base components as lightning web components with SLDS. But problem here is, SLDS Icons are not rendering on the app. I have imported salesforce-ux/design-system css file in the public/index.html file but icons are not cmoing up on ui though they are present in public/assets folder. As I am new to opensource web application frameworks, I am not able to figure out if I am missing any..

html code:

```
    <p id="action" class="slds-box slds-text-heading_small">Action icons represent actions a user can take. The default
    size of action icons are larger than the others. <br /><br />
    <lightning-icon icon-name="action:approval" alternative-text="Approved" title="Approved"></lightning-icon>
    <lightning-icon icon-name="action:delete" alternative-text="Delete" title="Delete"></lightning-icon>
    <lightning-icon icon-name="action:new_note" alternative-text="New note" title="New note"></lightning-icon>
    <lightning-icon icon-name="action:preview" alternative-text="Preview" title="Preview"></lightning-icon>
</p>
```

Output where icons are missing.

[image]

public/index.html

```
 <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css"
/>
```

express server.js

```
    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../public/index.html"));
});

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
);

(async () => {
  const watcher = await rollup.watch(config);
  watcher.on('event', (event) => {
    if (event.code === 'START') {
      console.log('Compiling...');
    }
    if (event.code === "END") {
      console.log('Done!');
    }
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

`lightning-base-components` does not use the SLDS standard assets to display icons, but rather uses a series of internal templates that are dynamically chosen at runtime. These are located in various template components, such as `lightning/iconSvgTemplatesStandard`. The build script for LWR appears to use `path.join` to form the complete module paths, but unfortunately, these components are not sanitized correctly. Looking at the compiled JavaScript for one of these components, you'll see it includes lines like:

```
import { default as standard_announcement } from '/1/module/esm/0/l/en-US/mi/lightning%2FiconSvgTemplatesStandard%23buildTemplates%5Cstandard%5Cannouncement.html%2Fv%2F1_19_6-alpha/latest/lightning_iconSvgTemplatesStandard_buildTemplates\standard\announcement_html.js';
```

If you scroll to the right, you'll see that it tries to include unescaped backslashes in the source:

```
...\standard\announcement_html.js
```

Which results in a runtime error that is logged to the console. This only happens on operating systems that use Windows path notation (i.e. Windows). On Linux systems, they will be properly rendered as:

```
..._standard_announcement_html.js
```

There's an [old bug](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/2981) that reports this, but it was closed. I am working on building a patch for this. In the meantime, the solution is to make sure you're running in a proper Linux environment, such as [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) (WSL) or a proper Linux host.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for prompt reply. I did try to use WSL, but no luck. It's been same. The old bug link you have shared is based on using LWR as runtime and I am using express server here. In lwr.config.json, there is a provison to mention where asset files are in but I am wondering, if we can also provide something like this for express server.

Also, after making change in primitiveIcon.js to fetch href() to return like ' /assets/icons/action-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#approval', Icons are started appearing.